# vim-fireplace cannot find source files when jumping to symbols

Tags: vim, clojure, leiningen, vim-plugin

I'm trying to set up vim-fireplace on Windows. Everything else works fine, but jumping to symbols with `[<C-d>` fails with error "Cannot find source file for [symbol name]".

After successful nrepl connection, `:echo fireplace#path()` returns `[]` which I guess causes the problem, because it should include the classpath. I can reproduce the problem with a `lein new` project. The exact same setup works fine on Linux. I've tried with and without the cider-nrepl Leiningen plugin.

Everything else works. Eval works, `[d` shows the source and `K` the doc strings for symbols.

I'd like to find out why vim-fireplace cannot establish the classpath, but I have no idea how to start debugging it. Can I somehow see what it sends and receives via the nrepl connection?

I'm using Leiningen 2.4.3, Clojure 1.6.0, GVim 7.4 with Python 2.7 and the latest vim-fireplace.

Any tips in debugging vim-fireplace are greatly appreciated!